# Angular cli is not installing. (npm warn deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: this functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs)

Tags: node.js, angular-cli

I installed node.js(18.12) first. Node.js is working. I want to install angular cli but it gives this error.

```
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
```

I deleted the Roaming (C:/Users/<your_user_name>/AppData/Roaming/npm) in the npm folder. I tried reinstalling but it didn't work. met with same error.

can you help me how to solve it...

Comment: That is a warning, not an error. There is no problem here.

Comment: ng help is not working. it says ng is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the latest version of nodejs (npm) cannot recognize the version of angular/cli to install.
You must point to the version you want to install.

Ex: `npm install -g  @angular/cli@11.2.18`